# Suggested Edit Have Some Bug

Tags: bug

Today I saw the bug on Review tab.

[image]

Comment: Community member should look this problem.

Comment: This is by design, not sure if this would change anytime soon though.

Comment: I think They the change the review listing algorithm

Answer (score 1):

This is not a bug, per se.

*I'll be calling them 10k tools, but in truth, on beta sites like this one, they are somewhat available at a lower reputation.*

Anyway, for users with access to the 10k tools,  the value at the top was changed a few days ago to include all available reviews count, not just the suggested edits queue.

Though a couple of points I read around SE sites:

- That value is cached (not sure if this one is completely true though, and for how long)
- The number shows the amount of *uncompleted* reviews. For example, if you go to the close votes queue and review all questions, the amount will not go down when you vote on a question which still needs more votes.

This is the case on all SE sites, except Stack Overflow which does not include the close votes queue in the total count.

Check the following question for more info on meta.se [Notification for reviews shows way too many](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230742/notification-for-reviews-shows-way-too-much) which somewhat a similar question.